# Is this sentence a question or a statement?

Tags: sentence-structure, questions, wh-questions

> What political journalist, what party whip, would not want to know the makeup of the WhatsApp groups in which Theresa May's enemies are currently plotting?

If this sentence is a question, then I don't understand why the word order for the sentence is "subject + verb". The usual word order for the interrogative sentence is:
(wh-word +) auxiliary + subject + verb

Is "What" in this sentence a question word?

Is this sentence a common linguistic phenomenon?

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically your sentence is definitely a question, but it does not have an inversion simply because ***What political journalist, what party whip*** is the Subject.

> ***Who*** would not want to know?

*If the question word is the subject of the verb*, no inversion is needed.

*If the question word is ***not*** the subject of the verb*, you need inversion and that is where auxiliaries 'pop up' :)

Comment: I have only seen cases in the subordinate clause that don't need to be inverted. eg: "I wonder who would not want to know. " So I‘m still confused about why the sentence is correct.

Comment: "[Does there exist a] journalist or whip [who] would not want to know...?"

Comment: @yllgl: in your example "I wonder who would not want to know. ", if you turned it into a direct question you would still have no inversion. "Who would not want to know?" But if you say "What matters would he not want to know?" - 'what' is a direct object of the verb 'to know', therefore the subject 'he' requires an inversion.